# wshshell icacls the handle is invalid

Tags: windows-hosting

I am using wshsell to call icacls to change a folder's permission.  And it returns the following error:

> C:\Windows\System32\icacls.exe C:\test\test1 /T /grant:r
>   IFC\ailen123staff-002:R
>
> Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
>   C:\test\test1: The handle is invalid.

This same command works if i put it in DOS prompt to run it. But it fails on my asp script.  I gave anonymous user as Administrator and it still fails.  Any idea?

It used to work , but it suddenly stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out.  It was the application pool user.  I changed the application pool user to administrator and the problem goes away.